# How can I delete an automatically created horizontal line in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

When I enter `---` in Word and press the Enter key, it automatically converts it to a horizontal line. That is okay, but how would I delete this line from my document?

Comment: What version of Word are you referring to? I am using 2010 and it doesn't do what you described. Also, there is no need to use greetings in questions.

Comment: then put Enter key

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in [this link](http://blogs.mccombs.utexas.edu/the-most/2012/10/03/removing-autoformatted-lines-in-microsoft-word/), you should go to the

1. *Home* tab
2. *Paragraph* box
3. click on *Borders*
4. Choose *No border*